# Does the rank of the Jacobian contain information about invertibility.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $m\geq n$ and consider  $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m: x\to f(x)$  continuous and differentiable. Does 
the rank of the Jacobian of $f$ (at a point $x_0$) contain any information of whether it has an (local) inverse?

I don't know, but have managed to google me to the multivariable inverse function theorem: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), but this seems to assume that $n = m$ for some reason, but I need it to hold also if $m>n$. Is it still true? A source would be plenty.

Comment: Maybe constant rank theorem is usefull?

Comment: If $m > n$, a differentiable $f$ has an image that is nowhere dense and has Lebesgue measure $0$. What sort of a "local inverse" are you after? If only after a local inverse defined on the image of $f$, then you have local inverses where the rank is $n$. If after local inverses defined on open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$, that is impossible for $m > n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmm.. It would be great if it were for a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$, but it can be chosen nice if that helps. If it gets nasty then on the image will suffice. If i consider the function onto its image and the rank is everywhere n is the function then bijective? Is that condition stronger or equivalent to it being a bijection?

Comment: @daw it might be, but it will take me a bit of time to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derivatives can only tell you about local invertibility; global invertibility is a totally different matter.  This answer focuses on local inverse, and on the case when the Jacobian has rank $ n$.

The Jacobian matrix at $\mathbf x_0$   has more rows than columns. By assumption, its columns are linearly independent. You can add extra columns to this matrix so it gets into square shape, and becomes invertible. (A linearly independent set of vectors can be extended to a basis.)

Adding columns $v_{n+1},\dots,v_m$ means  introducing  extra dimensions $x_{n+1},\dots,x_m$ to the domain, and extending $f$ to the map 
$$
F(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1},\dots,x_m) = 
f(x_1,\dots,x_n) + \sum_{i=n+1}^{m}  x_i  v_{i}   
$$
where  $v_{n+1},\dots,v_m$ are constant vectors in $\mathbb R^m$. You can check that the Jacobian of $F$ consists of the Jacobian of $f$ with those extra columns $v_{n+1},\dots,v_m$.

Applying the inverse function theorem to $F$, we get a smooth inverse map $F^{-1}$. It goes from some neighborhood $U$ of $f(\mathbf x_0)$ in $\mathbb R^{m}$ into $\mathbb R^{m}$. We can disregard the added dimensions now, projecting back to $\mathbb R^n$. The result is a smooth map $g$ from $U$ to $\mathbb R^n$. It satisfies $g(  f(x)) = x$.

The composition $f\circ g$ is also an interesting map: it is a smooth projection from $U$ onto the image of a neighborhood of $\mathbf x_0$ under $f$. The above construction also shows that this image is a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold.